Type of caulk bathroom counter and painted wall?
New construction home and what kind of caulk is used between the bathroom counter and painted dry wall? I don’t think it’s compound. Is it silicone caulk that had dried out and cracking? If it is all I do is remove old silicone caulk and clean up and then apply?
I see the bathroom counter to tiles backslash is silicone caulk. Then tiled to painted drywall is compound. Just not sure with counter to drywall.



I would guess that it is acrylic latex caulk. That’s the same type of caulk you’d use for baseboards and trim.

That definitely is acrylic latex caulk.  Niko, put your comment in an answer for an upvote.

How does acrylic caullk crack so fast in new construction?

I can't see on the picture if the caulk is cracked, or if the paint that covers it is cracked.
If the paint is cracked but not the caulk, it's probably silicone. Silicone cannot be painted, and if you attempt to paint it, paint will not stick and will end up cracking and flaking off.
If the caulk is cracked, it's probably extra-cheap low quality acrylic, or maybe not compatible with the paint. Good acrylic doesn't do that.
You should remove it and replace with silicone.

That is acrylic latex caulk. Your plan is correct. Remove all the old caulk and apply a fresh bead down.
